# Creating a Timesheet with at different rates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Scenario:**

I have an excel Timesheet which needs to calculate Standard Time 1x, Overtime 1.5x, Overtime 2x based on the following values:

1. If the start time and finish time fall between 08:00 and 16:45, then sum the hours x1
2. If the finish time falls between 16:45 and 00:00, then sum the hours by x1.5
3. If the finish time falls between 00:00 and 08:00 then sum hours by x2

**Example Data:**

```
Start time  Finish time Standard time   Overtime x1.5   Overtime x2
08:30:00     17:00:00       7.5             0.5              0
17:00:00     01:00:00       0               7                1
01:00:00     10:00:00       2               0                7
06:00:00     12:00:00       4               0                2
```

I have been racking my brain and possible ways to do this but keep falling short, does anybody know how I would go about creating a formula to do this kind of some?

Comment: I would add two columns in `C:D` for your standard hours, so start time in col `C` as 8:00 and end in col `D` as 16:45. You can then calculate the hours done in standard time with something like `=IF(AND(A2>C2, B2<D2), B2-A2, IF(B2>D2, D2-A2))` which checks if the start and finish are both in regular hours, then if the end time is after it calculates the start time up to 16:45. Then for your overtime 1.5 do similar, if your end time is after 16:45 calculate how much after with `=IF(B2>D2, (B2-D2)*1.5, 0)`. Format all your cells as custom `h:mm` This should be a start.

Comment: If I add 08:00 in C2 and 16:45 in D2, what are A2 and B2 referencing in your formula above?

Comment: From your first row A2 is your start time 8:30:00 and B2 finish time 17:00:00. The above is not complete by any stretch, but you need to break it down into different outcomes. Just realised to check start and end aren't both outside 8:00-16:45 `=IF(AND(D2>A2>C2, C2<B2<D2), B2-A2, IF(B2>D2, D2-A2))` is better.

Comment: You need to be careful with the shift 17:00 -> 01:00 becuase if unless you define 01:00 as 8 hours after 17:00 then Excel will see 01:00 as before 17:00.  you can work around this by capturing the start (17:00), the duration (08:00) and then calculate the finish time as start+duration that way excel knows that 01:00-17:00 = 08:00.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have a working example but it involves creating a matrix of times from 08:00 to 07:30 the following morning at 30min intervals and a simple if statement to put a 1 under the header time if it falls within the shift start and finish times.

Comment: im working on something similar at present with a time matrix, it doesn't matter about the amount of rows used, I can hide those :), thankyou all for your help so far

Comment: I would always go back to the standard formula for calculating overlaps, max(0,min(start1,start2)-max(end1,end2)) but as Gordon rightly says you have to watch out for times that cross day boundaries.

Comment: BTW are their some coffee breaks in the first row of data? The total hours worked are 9 1/2 but only 8 hours accounted for.

Comment: I haven't factored that in yet, but at some point i will after add that in, it will vary from 0.00 till 1.00 hour for a coffee break

Comment: Here's my matrix version http://www.scotlang.com/Overtime.xlsx  Doing this as one formula would be crazy complicated.  It does 30 min intervals but it could be scaled up if required.  You could add a couple of columns for break start and and break duration to record that in the matrix.

Comment: thats a great idea, if you add that as an answer Ill accept it, works a treat,

Comment: I've posted an answer and noticed a near fatal flaw.  When entering a shift that starts after 00:00 e.g. 01:00 or 06:00, the time needs to be the time entered + 24 hours otherwise it is not recognised as being within the matrix range.  I notced this while trying to build another version that has a matrix of times and overtime classification 1.5x, 2x etc.I'll update my answer when I find a solution.

Comment: thats no problem, I keep checking back, thanks for the help

Comment: I've updatded the example file so that it starts from 00:00 and continues for 24 hours.  This ensures that a shift that start at say 23:00 and continues into the next morning is captured and calculated correctly  The sum ranges are more complicated so I've categorised each matrix enrty as Standard, x 1.5 or x 2 so that a sumif can be used.  I'm going to create a version that uses a lookup table of times and overtime category so that by using countifs we can get the number of hours without having the 1s and 0s next to every row and it can be very accurate if every minute is accounted for.

Comment: I'd like to complement @Gordon's nice answer with one using the formula mentioned previously but won't have a chance until this evening i.e. in at least 3 hours time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a matrix of times and use an if statement to determine if the time falls within the shift or not.  Sum the times as required for each shift.

Here's a link to my example http://www.scotlang.com/Overtime.xlsx.

[image: Shcreenshot]

Comment: Final update.  I've added a sheet that contains a list of times and rates for a 48 hour period.  Using countifs with the start and finish times it's possible to calculate the time to be allocated to each rate.  This has been a useful excecise for me as I can hopfully avoid the pitfalls of making time calculations in the future.

Comment: works perfect thankyou, I though this would have caused some performance issues however it works a treat, cheers

Comment: if i want to add the finish time myself, it breaks, any ideas how I can get around this? it saves someone having to calculate the duration out, cheers for any help

Comment: It breaks because behind each time that is entered or calculated Excel stores it as a date something like 0/0/1900 and that's why it sees 23:00+02:00 as different from 01:00 when entered into a cell. You could try a formula that can fix the finish date. I think Tom's answer addresses the issue.  I'll try a couple of things.

Comment: Here's a formula that you can use to get the*real* finish time if someone enters 23:00 and 01:00.  As the duration column in my example is only being used to calculate the finish time you could change the heading to Finish and put this formula in column C `=IF(A3>B3,A3+(1-A3)+B3,B3)`  If the start date is greater than the finish date then it will do 23:00+(24:00-23:00)+01:00 The 24:00 is represented as 1 in the formula.

Comment: You may want to add a duration column somewhere to highlight if a user mistakenly enters 08:00 - 04:00 thinking that it means 8am to 4pm.  The duration calculated would be 20 hours instead of their expected 7.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I am too late as the other answer has been accepted which is great if it covers a 48-hour period. Anyway this is how mine looks - can provide some explanation later.

[image]

Here are the definitions relative to cell D2

[image]

So the basic formula is

```
=MAX(0,MIN(ClockOff+Split,ShiftEnd)-MAX(ClockOn,ShiftStart))
```

This is based on the standard formula for calculating the overlap of two ranges quoted in various places e.g. [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28296518/Excel-calculating-overlapping-period-of-two-date-ranges.html) but adds 1 (equal to one whole day) for the case when the end of shift is after midnight. This works for standard time (starting in D2) and overtime X 1.5 (starting in E2) as long as the end of the evening shift (in J4) is also entered as 1 whole day (24:00 hours). For overtime X 2, both the start of shift (0:00) and end of shift (08:00) have to be adjusted by 24 hours if the hours worked are split across midnight so the formula in F2 is

```
=MAX(0,MIN(ClockOff+Split,ShiftEnd+Split)-MAX(ClockOn,ShiftStart+Split))
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer, I will look into this later :) a completely different approach.